# CSS to fill width with icon at the end (search box)

Tags: css

I'm trying to do this: [image]

(The search button has fixed size, the left side takes remaining width in screen).

The best I got yet: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skY5C/1/)

[image]

HTML:

```
<input>
<img src="http://ii.alatest.com/css/iphone/search_icon.gif">
```

CSS:

```
input {
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
}

img {
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, the search icon has to be clickable! This leads probably to a solution where it's a separate element, not a part of the background.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using the image as a background to the input like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/skY5C/2/)**.

```
input {
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
    padding-right:120px;
    background-image: url(http://ii.alatest.com/css/iphone/search_icon.gif);
    background-position: 98% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Or, you can float both elements left and set a width on the input like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/skY5C/3/)**.

```
input {
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 3em;
    width: 70%;
    float:left;
}

img {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to float the textbox now.

Comment: @UzairSajid - true, the `float:left` rule could be removed from the first example.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention (although, it could be guessed by the context), that I need the search icon to be clickable. So I'm left only with the second option?